# Python Requests - Subsequent Cookie Usage

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to use Requests to do the API calls.
We are supposed to do an AuthenticatedSession and use the Cookie from that session to get the next request.

When i try to do that it gives me 401 error [ Authentication problem ]

```
def request_data(request_url, user, password, apiKey):
# These are the headers that will be passed with requests.
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
# This headers sets where to start reporting from.
payload = {'apiKey': apiKey}
# Create the request session variable.
session = requests.Session()
# Build and make the request with url and your headers, auth, payload( reset value ).
# The first time is just to set the reset and get your auth/feed cookie.
resp = session.get(request_url, headers=headers, auth=(user, password), params=payload)

URL = 'https://admin.zscalerbeta.net/api/v1/urlCategories'
resp1 = session.get(URL)
return resp , session , resp1


def main():
# Hardcoded login details.
# This can be modifed to populate values from command line or config file.
# make call to request function and return json
resp , session , resp1 = request_data(auth_url, user, password, apiKey)
# This is just a sanity check print to verify you see your json data and cookies.
print(json.dumps(resp.json(), indent=4, sort_keys=True))
print(resp.cookies)
print(resp)
print(resp1)
# Checking URL Categories.

### SCRIPT ENTRY POINT ####    
if __name__ == '__main__':
# Call to the main function.
main()
```

Output of this :

```
{
"obfuscateApiKey": true
}
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie JSESSIONID=9016354002CA0467A95DB87E913DEC84 for admin.zscalerbeta.net/>]>
<Response [200]>
<Response [401]>
```

I need help on how i can get this working.